# How to query across 2 different tables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_id, :result, :user_id
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :prompt, :topic
end
```

I have the following 2 models above in my Rails app. I'd like to run a query that selects questions that have a certain topic (Math) but that are unanswered for a given user_id (result = "Unanswered").

I'm having trouble coming up with the query that would get this.

```
first_question = Question.where(:topic => "Math")
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate the `:result => "Unanswered"` from the `Answer` table. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `joins` to do an inner join between the `questions` and `answers` table, then `merge` a query for `:result => "Unanswered"`:

```
Question.joins(:answer).where(:topic => "Math", :user_id => <user_id>).merge(Answer.where(:result => "Unanswered"))
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all unanswered questions for user #1 under the MATH topic use:

```
Question.includes(:answers).where(:topic => 'MATH', 'answers.result' => 'Unanswered', 'answers.user_id' => 1)
```

If you want to just get the first unanswered question:

```
Question.includes(:answers).where(:topic => 'MATH', 'answers.result' => 'Unanswered', 'answers.user_id' => 1).first
```

I might create some scopes to make these easier to reuse:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers

  scope :topic, lambda {|topic|
    where(:topic => topic)
  }

  scope :unanswered_by, lambda { |user|
    includes(:answers).where('answers.result' => 'Unanswered', 'answers.user_id' => user.id)
  }

end
```

So you can then query like this:

```
user = User.last
Question.topic('MATH').unanswered_by(user)
```